# django-rest-framework: how do I update a nested foreign key? My update method is not even called

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have something like this (I only included the relevant parts):

```py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  telescopes = TelescopeSerializer(many=True)

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # In this method I would perform the update of the telescopes if needed.
    # The following line is not executed.
    return super().update(instance, validated_data)

  class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = ('title', 'telescopes',)
```

When I perform a `GET`, I get nested data just as I want, e.g.:

```json
{
  'title': 'Some image',
  'telescopes': [
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Foo'
  ]
}
```

Now, if I want to update this image, by changing the name but not the telescopes, I would `PUT` the following:

```json
{
  'title': 'A new title',
  'telescopes': [
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Foo'
  ]
}
```

It seems that `django-rest-framework` is not even calling my `update` method because the model validation fails (`Telescope.name` has a `unique` constraint), and `django-rest-framework` is validating it as if it wanted to create it?

Things worked fine when I wasn't using a nested serializer, but just a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, but I do need the nested serializer for performance reason (to avoid too many API calls).

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: @RamiAwar it's been a long time so I'm not sure how I solved it. If I look at the code now, I see that my Image serializer has this field: `telescopes = TelescopeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` so perhaps the `read_only` is what does it. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score -1):

You'll find your solution here
[Django rest relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)